# How access Node console log

Tags: node.js

So I am uploading my Node code to a device and so I cannot really see the console and hence cannot see the log. I was wondering if there was any way to 'access' the log using HTTP? I know when console.log() is called it writes to process.stdout.

I tried process.stdout.pipe(response) //inside a proper HTTP server code block of course. But it did not work.

Any suggestions?

TIA

Comment: it depends on the server you are uploading the files to. usually they provide the command to see the log files on your computer. Which server/service are you uploading to?

Comment: Its a device we are hosting ourselves on a LAN. Apparently we can SSH into the device and get the Node log but tech support hasnt gotten back to me with all the details yet so I was wondering if there is a lightweight solution. I just want to see it for debugging purposes in development.

Comment: you can probably run the application with a single computer as server. This server will display the log.

Comment: ah but I feel the bug might exist due to the specific environment of the device the Node app is running in :-/

Comment: no no. node should not depend on the 'specific environment' at all!

Comment: ok ill give it a shot!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing as @Sangram Singh suggested and hosted my Node app on my local machine for now and debugging it here. Luckily the errors I am getting are the same as the errors I was getting when it was hosted on the device.

Niko